# i have created splash screen but it does not resume if i change the screen

Tags: java, swing, splash-screen

i have written this code..

```
package splashscreen;

/**
 * @author LENOVO
 */
public class Splashscreen {

    public Splashscreen() {
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        sleepThread();

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater( new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible( true );
            }
        } );
    }

    private static void sleepThread() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep( 5000 );
        } catch( InterruptedException ex ) {
            // Do something, if there is a exception
            System.out.println( ex.toString() );
        }
    }
}
```

it is able to run but doesn't resume again if i changed the screen..

Comment: I do not understand your problem. Your Application starts, then wait 5 seconds, then show a new `JFrame`.

Comment: please whats wrong with code from official Oracle tutotial How to Splash Screen

Comment: Did you check [How to create splash screen in java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html) ?

Comment: yes application starts then wait 5 seconds and in between that if i change the screen so i m unable to resume after changing the screen again..